# What is the use of assert in the following program creating a linked list? Isn't it useless?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, tree

```
bool isTree(List<Object> tree) {
  if ((tree is! List) | (tree.length < 1)) {
    return false;
  }
  for (final branch in branches(tree)) {
    if (!isTree(branch)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

List branches(List tree) {
  return tree.sublist(1);
}

Object label(List tree) {
  return tree[0];
}

List tree(rootLabel, [List branches = const []]) {
  for (final branch in branches) {
    assert(isTree(branch));
  }
  return ([rootLabel] + branches);
}

bool isLeaf(List tree) {
  return branches(tree).isEmpty;
}

var t = tree('hey', [
  tree('hello'),
  tree('hum', [tree('there'), tree('hey')])
]);
```

If i were to remove the for loop with the assert function, and also the is_tree function, the program still returns the same results as with them, So aren't they useless?

```
List branches(List tree) {
  return tree.sublist(1);
}

Object label(List tree) {
  return tree[0];
}

List tree(rootLabel, [List branches = const []]) {
  
  return ([rootLabel] + branches);
}

bool isLeaf(List tree) {
  return branches(tree).isEmpty;
}

var t = tree('hey', [
  tree('hello'),
  tree('hum', [tree('there'), tree('hey')])
]);
```

Here is the full tutorial when i am learning this https://composingprograms.com/pages/23-sequences.html#trees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's there to make sure all branches are trees. Without the assert you are able to write this without any errors.

```
var t = tree('hey', ['notATree']);
```

With the assert it will throw an error.

Comment: Ok cool, But even if enable asserts with terminal, and run it to get assertion error, I am not getting any errors. Assertions were disabled by default on dart right.. But even if i run the ```var t = tree('hey', ['notATree']);``` with asserts i am not getting any errors :/

Comment: @zram I don't know anything about that. I run dart in IntelliJ and there it does throw the error with my example.

Comment: I am running it in VScode though...Its not showing me assertion errors.. Does IntelliJ free supports dart

Comment: @zram also, I'd like to point out that your way of coding in dart is very unidiomatic. It's more idiomatic to work with static types. You left almost everything dynamic. That's much more error prone. When using static types wherever possible you also don't need any assertions I believe

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will try to make it more static and correct.

Comment: Hi i made some changes in the original program Can you please tell me if i have done it correctly. I cant figure out what to put for rootlabel cuz whatever i put it returns some error lol. :/

Comment: @zram personally I would rework your tree as a class. Something like this: https://pastebin.com/091ANepy . But of course it's also a bit subjective, and depends on the use case. And I don't mean to be rude, but I don't want to spend more time on your issue. I hope you can figure it out on your own

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to have answered my questions, I do understand your point of view as well. I would have done the same. I am still learning , So haven't gotten to the point of OOP classes just yet, I will definitely try to re-write the whole thing in a class as well once i learn more. Thanks again for taking the time to have replied! I have copied your pastebin code for study !